# How can I debug T4 templates inside Sql Server database projects?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, t4, sql-server-data-tools

In any other project, any time I want to debug a template, I simply right-click the .tt file and choose "Debug T4 template" command in the contextual menu.

However, this command doesn't appear when the .tt file is inside a Sql Server database project.

Do I have something special to do to allow this feature? Or is there another way I can debug a template?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Workaround: Create a C# Class Library project and add the .tt file _[as a link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9f4t9t92(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_0)_ or put the .csproj in the same folder as the other project. (I, too, an frustrated that some specialized project types shut out general project features.)

Comment: @TomBlodget Interesting. I'll give it a shot ASAIC. Thanks.